# NTFS Access parameter Error - powershell script

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I am trying to add permissions to files, but I cant figure out what it needs from me and I get this error:

```
Add-NTFSAccess : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:22 char:21
+ ...             Add-NTFSAccess "$Folder\$Subfolder" -Account "$Level" -Acces ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-NTFSAccess], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,NTFSSecurity.AddAccess
```

This is command I am using for adding permissions, loops are only ilustrative, so it is clear what parameters I am passing in.

```
for Folder in folders:
 for SubFolder in Folder:
  for Level in Levels:
    Add-NTFSAccess "$Folder\$Subfolder" -Account "$Level" -AccessRights Modify -PassThru -InheritanceFlags ObjectInherit -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles | Out-Null
```

Does somebody now, what parameters it wants from me or what is the error telling me? I started working with this only today, so I am quite lost.

Comment: It seems you cannot use parameters `-InheritanceFlags` and `-AppliesTo` in the same command, because these parameters are from different parameter sets See [Add-NTFSAccess](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cmdlets/Add-NTFSAccess/)

Comment: Thanks, after removing it it works.